# What's the most efficient way to assure the row counts are increased in an HBase table at this very moment?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'd like to assure that data are stored in an HBase table at this very moment. I don't need the exact row count. For that I'm executing `count 'table_name'` command twice in HBase shell:

```
hbase(main):001:0> count 'test_table', 100000
...
558549 row(s) in 360.1440 seconds

hbase(main):001:0> count 'test_table', 100000
...
558623 row(s) in 354.0270 seconds
```

But it takes too long when the row count is big(> 200,000).

What's the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the count command with a bigger cache value, I think the default one is 10

```
count 'test_table', CACHE => 1000
```

If it still too slow, you should try using the MapReduce Job

```
Run '$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar hbase.jar rowcount'
```